# C language and Haskell

Tags: haskell

The C language is actually a kind of imperative language .

Haskell I suppose is completely different since it's a functional programming language.

Coming from C (not being an expert) , what are the main troubles I'm bound to face in order to achieve a sufficient level of knowledge with Haskell?

Thanks

Melawe

Comment: Sorry, but I think that's hardly an answerable question. Coming from dynamically typed imperative/OO languages, I find the *functional* aspect of Haskell hardly worth mentioning. What gets me is the *type system*. This completely depends on your personal experience...

Comment: I meant things like : in Haskell you can use a variable without declaring it , you can use function as variables,types declarations are different from C...I suppose is a completely different attitude towards programming...

Comment: Well, yes, it is. So it's hard to tell you what you'll have the most troubles with. In the end you can do functional programming in C as well (to some extend) by writing everything as function calls nested in functions calls. The more you already practice this in other languages the better you are prepared to work with a functional language.

Comment: @Melawe How about there are no variables? (Simply expressions bound to a name ;) )

Comment: maybe some math can help. category theory, group theory, Homological Algebra, Topology.

Answer (score 5):

A non exhaustive list:

- `return` doesn't mean what you think it means.
- `if`-`then`-`else` is more like C's `?`-`:` than C's `if`-`else`. In particular, the else branch is not optional.
- Indentation matters. Be especially careful when you use `if`-`then`-`else` within a `do` block.
- No implicit casting. (There are functions for explicitly converting between different numeric types, which is where you'll get tripped up most often by this.)
- No C-style loops. Instead use `map`/`fmap`/`<$>`, `foldr` / other folding functions, `filter`, `zip`/`zipWith`/etc, or list comprehensions depending on what your "loop" does. (And recursion is available should you need it.)
- Mutable state is awkward to use (and usually a wrong solution).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your definition of "sufficient". Haskell monads can be notoriously difficult to master, but you should be able to get the ground running by starting with simple exercises so that you get used to thinking in a "functional way", and gaining familiarity with the type system. As a beginner, I strongly urge you to get your hands on [Programming in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html).

Answer (score 0):

The main trouble? You'll miss mutable structures at first, I guess.

At least, that's what happens to me when I get hands on a functional language after spending too much time working with procedural languages.